# How to know which page is redirected? in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to determine which page is redirected?

i am using this code but this is not helping what i am looking for:

```
   $(function () {             
        //var locate = window.location;
        //var t = window.location.hash;
        var pagename = location.pathname.substr(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, location.pathname.length).toLowerCase();
        if (pagename == "toppages.aspx") {
            $('#back_to_your_list').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#back_to_your_list').hide();
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

So, I have a link on my home page (`mydomain.com/employee/default.aspx`) and once the user click on it then this will redirect to another page (`mydomain.com/employee/toppages.aspx`) from it there are other links and say the user click on a link called `Background check` and this will redirect to a different page and this time the url of this page will be  (`mydomain.com/employee/toppages.aspx?id=123`)

the logic should be.

if the page is coming from `mydomain.com/employee/toppages.aspx?id=123` then `$('#back_to_your_list').show();` otherwise `hide`

i hope it make sense and confused :)

Comment: show the structure of your URL, it will make more sense

Comment: What do you mean with "redirected"???

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer ?

Comment: updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: @Bergi: redirected meaning - click the link (a href)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know what was the page on which a link was clicked leading to your page, simply  use the referrer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer

A browser may be instructed to block it.
A different (hackish) solution for your own site could simply be to store the page in localStorage :

```
   var lastPage;
   $(function() {
        var lastPage = localStorage['lastPage'];
        localStorage['lastPage'] = document.location.pathname;
   });
```

Comment: i tried using `var _ref = document.referrer; ` and i am getting empty string

Comment: I added a different solution but it works only when you go from your site to a different page of the same site.

Comment: where exaclty the line of code goes? if i put on the js tag then everytime the page loads it will override isn't?

Comment: I edited to make it more clear. Once this function (called by jquery onready) is called, you have the last page location pathname in the `lastPage` variable.

Comment: @dystroy: You don't need DOMready for localStorage or location